# Docker-machine can't use userdata add key to ssh cloud image

Tags: ssh, openstack, docker-machine, cloud-init

- My provider : OpenStack
- VM OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Docker-machine Version: 0.14.0
- Problem:

  - I want to use userdata add another public key to authorized_keys, 
    using --openstack-user-data-file option to specify my userdata.yml.

Here is my userdata.yml:

`#cloud-config
users:
  - default
  - name: ubuntu
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Use docker-machine command to create vm:

`docker-machine --debug create --driver openstack 
--openstack-auth-url http://x.x.x.x:5001/v3 
--openstack-domain-id defaule
 --openstack-endpoint-type adminURL 
--openstack-floatingip-pool ext-net 
--openstack-keypair-name mykey
--openstack-flavor-id 4 
--openstack-image-name ubuntu-16.04-cloud 
--openstack-net-name private 
--openstack-password XXXXX 
--openstack-private-key-file /home/demo/id_rsa
--openstack-sec-groups default 
--openstack-ssh-user ubuntu
--openstack-tenant-name admin
--openstack-user-data-file /home/demo/userdata.yml 
--openstack-username admin 
vm`

After creating vm , docker-machine stuck " waiting for ssh to be available".
Here is debug output:

`Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(vm) Calling .GetSSHHostname
(vm) Calling .GetSSHPort
(vm) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(vm) Calling .GetSSHKeyPath
(vm) Calling .GetSSHUsername
Using SSH client type: external
Using SSH private key: /root/.docker/machine/machines/vm/id_rsa (-rw-------)
&{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none ubuntu@10.50.2.36 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /root/.docker/machine/machines/vm/id_rsa -p 22] /usr/bin/ssh <nil>}
About to run SSH command:
exit 0
SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255: 
Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : ssh command error:
command : exit 0
err     : exit status 255
output  :`

I try to ssh to vm by command:
`ssh -i /root/.docker/machine/machines/vm/id_rsa ubuntu@10.50.2.36`

But got error message: 
`Permission denied (publickey).`

So, I try another key , the key was in option of --openstack-private-key-file  /home/demo/id_rsa

`ssh -i  /home/demo/id_rsa ubuntu@10.50.2.36`

ssh was successful!

I checked two keys,  **/root/.docker/machine/machines/vm/id_rsa** and **/home/demo/id_rsa,**
but two keys are the same.

I was confused,  why the same keys, one can ssh another one can't ssh?

Answer (score 0):

In order for Docker-Machine to set-up a virtual machine on OpenStack, you need to activate the [config_drive](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/queens/user/config-drive.html) option: `docker-machine --openstack-config-drive [OTHER_OPTIONS] <MACHINE_NAME>`